# phpMyAdmin incorrect username/password

Tags: phpmyadmin, passwords

I'm running custombuild on my local server and installed phpMyAdmin as described and every things working but phpMyAdmin.

I've set a root password upon entering the mysql console from CLI but the password is rejected, and I've created a test account monty which is being rejected also.

The auth.log file is showing this:

```
Apr 03 11:02:51:: pma auth user='monty' status='mysql-denied' ip='192.168.1.70'
Apr 03 11:07:24:: pma auth user='root' status='mysql-denied' ip='192.168.1.70'
```

I've been working on this all day and can't find the problem. It would appear that phpMyAdmin is calling a different mysql process than the one I'm using on CLI.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent far too much time on this and ended up formatting the server, downgrading to custombuild 1.2 (used to install and manage mysql/phpmyadmin) and it worked.

GO FIGURE.